# Android Studio 2.2 beta 3 help setting up for cmake

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I believe I keep installing the incorrect gradle to make any c programs work. How exactly can I obtain and install the item which allows me to deal with the following:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta2'}
```

I tried installing android 2.4, but that didn't work.

If it is simply and issue of the distribution url can someone please give it to me?

Comment: latest one should use gradle version 2.14.1 for android plugin 2.2.0. it should be set inside file gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties.  If you open an existing project, Android Studio would prompt you for it

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Forgot to respond to this